# AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM) -- Is there a versionFunctions equivalent?

Tags: aws-sam

I'm using AWS Lambda and it often exceeds the code storage limit because there are too many old version. I want to prevent Lambda to generate a new version for each deployment.

I found in serverless framework, you can achieve this by set the versionFunctions to false in serverless.yml. However, I found my application use SAM. Is there an equivalent or other way to do this in SAM?

Comment: As far as I know, versioning is disabled by default in SAM. Do you have a AutoPublishAlias in you template perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I checked my template contains ```AutoPublishAlias: live```.

Comment: Then just remove it. Judging from your question, it doesn't seem you're taking advantage of versioning and aliasing your Lambda function. Without `AutoPublishAlias` SAM will stop creating new versions on each deploy, you will have only a single version (`$LATEST`) available.